# python google_auth_oauthlib Out Of Band (OOB) error

Tags: python, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to run an internal app (this is a simple script) and authenticating using OAuth with python. But I run into the following error when I click on the link to authenticate my user after running my script :

> The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure. Follow the Out-of-Band (OOB) flow migration guide linked in the developer docs below to migrate your app to an alternative method.
> Détails de la requête : redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

Here is my code :

```py
# More code

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow

# More code

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"]

# More code

def upload():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    # os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    client_secrets_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "client_secrets.json"))

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
```

And my `client_secrets.json` :

```json
{
    "installed": {
        "client_id": "**********",
        "project_id": "MY-PROJECT-ID",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "*****",
        "redirect_uris": [
            "http://localhost:3000"
        ]
    }
}
```

But the URL to retrieve the code to authenticate is still :
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=*********&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.upload&state=******&prompt=consent&access_type=offline`

As you can see the url **still uses oob** and I didn't find any way to make it change to use localhost instead.

I run pip library versions :

```bash
pip list
oauthlib                 3.2.2
requests-oauthlib        1.3.1
google-api-python-client 2.66.0
google-auth              2.14.1
google-auth-httplib2     0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib     0.7.1
googleapis-common-protos 1.57.0
http-client              0.1.22
httplib2                 0.21.0
```

and using `python 3.10.7`

- I already check this doc, for desktop app it just says "use loopback url": https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/resources/oob-migration
- I also read this to use address loopback properly but didn't work: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#handlingresponse
- I tried running a local webserver launched with `python -m http.server 3000` to listen events on the loopback but it didn't work

Do you have any idea on how to make this work?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

First off make sure that you have updated the client library.  Im not sure which version you are running but the library was fixed about a year ago.

Second remove the port.

```
"redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]
```

Third

If that doesn't work here is my sample for videos.insert it should work out of the box.

```
#   To install the Google client library for Python, run the following command:
#   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

import google.auth.exceptions
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']

def main():

    """Shows basic usage of the YouTube v3 API.
    Uploads a private video to YouTube
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        try:
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
            creds.refresh(Request())
        except google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError as error:
            # if refresh token fails, reset creds to none.
            #creds = None
            print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        body = dict(
            snippet=dict(
                title="Test",
                description="test",
                tags="tes"
            ),
            status=dict(
                privacyStatus="private"
            )
        )

        media = MediaFileUpload("dummyvideo.mkv", chunksize=-1, resumable=True)

        results = service.videos().insert(
                part=",".join(body.keys()),
                body=body,
                media_body=media).execute()
        print(F'video ID: {results.get("id")}')

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## version of google api python client

I am running these versions of the relevant google apis python library

```
pip list

google-api-core          2.10.1
google-api-python-client 2.62.0
requests-oauthlib        1.3.1
```

I think oauthlib may be part of it as well.

Comment: Hello ! Thank you very much for your answer !
When you say to update the client library you mean with `pipenv install google_auth_oauthlib` for example ? For this one I think the version used is `==0.7.1` and I am running on python 3.10.7

Comment: sorry i am a sample creator not exactly the best to Python.   Just make sure you have the latest version of   google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

Comment: maybe something like pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

Comment: or a bit of googling says try pip list.

Comment: Ok thank you ! It was just to be sure I understood your point about version ! 